# Yii2 transform 'string' datetime to int(11) datetime

Tags: php, datetime, yii2, timestamp

yii2 have a function that transform something like '1671380485' to 'December 21, 2022'.

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('1671380485', 'medium');
```

Do yii2 have a function that will make Reverse effect? For example transform '2022-12-21' to int(11)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe PHP's [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function is what you are looking for:

```php
<?php
echo strtotime('2022-12-21'); // 1671606000
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the built-in formatter:

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asTimestamp('2022-12-21');
```

Read more here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#asTimestamp()-detail